Should I cast to string and then to int for mypy?
I have a config I loaded up into a dict. It contains an integer config["logging"]["backup_count"]. However, type(config["logging"]["backup_count"]) returns object. So, when I go to pass this into the following:
TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, backupCount=config["logging"]["backup_count"], when="midnight", interval=1)

mypy complains that I am trying to put an object where an int is expected. Of course, this is fixable by adding some type-casting:
TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, backupCount=int(str(config["logging"]["backup_count"])), when="midnight", interval=1)

but this seems clunky. Should I be doing this?
I'm new to mypy and typing in python. I'd like to know the proper protocol for dealing with something like this. Specifically, should I be doing the -to-str-to-int cast or something else?
EDIT: Should I use TypedDict? If my dictionary is being read out of a .toml file for example, is there an easy way to create a TypedDict from this with the correct typing (I know what the config types are supposed to be ahead of time)?

Is there an error there? I mean, can the python code be run without terminating with a ValueError, TypeError or something?

There's no error when running the script. Only an error when calling mypy on the script to type-check.

If that's the case, then just ignore it.

How is config define? You probably want to define one or more TypedDicts so that mypy knows exactly what type is associated with each key.

if type(thing) returns object at runtime, no amount of "casting"  will turn it into an int.  This is not C++ or Java where an object can be "perceived as" one of its superclasses by casting  - an int, being a subclass can "do everything an 'object' does", but it has more things (like having a value). And type will always return the actual class of an instance.

@jsbueno I completely agree, an object is an object, it cannot become an int.

@LukeL   I think the O.P. is talking about type as what he gets with mypy introspection, not a runtime call to the built-in type - which is what I thought when writing the comment above - in that case it makes sense

You should define TypedDicts that specify exactly what the type of config["logging"]["backup_count"] is. A minimal demonstration:
from typing import TypedDict


class LoggingConfig(TypedDict):
    backup_count: int

class Config(TypedDict):
    logging: LoggingConfig


config: Config = {"logging": {"backup_count": 3}}

reveal_type(config["logging"]["backup_count"])  # int

A quicker workaround is, assuming you trust that config["logging"]["backup_cont"] really is an int, to just tell mypy:
from typing import cast

TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, backupCount=cast(int, config["logging"]["backup_count"]), when="midnight", interval=1)

(There is still the overhead of a call to cast, but at runtime, all it does is return its second argument, rather than actually creating a new int value. When type-checking, mypy assumes the second argument has the type specified by the first.)

I think your answer is just over-complicating things. MyPy is just a type checker, not a language compiler. OP's comment confirmed that passing-in object won't raise an error, so that means TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__() can actually accept an object instead of an int, so there's no problem here. It's not like passing object will break the program.

Some people sometimes just focusses on answering the specific problem the asker is asking about, without realizing that that problem doesn't even exists or matters. In these cases, the best solution or answer is to inform the asker that their problem doesn't exist, so that they don't get all caught up in these sort of things and waste a whole lot of time. My answer is based on that, while your answer is one of those who answers the problem perfectly, but doesn't realize that the issue (typing complaints of mypy in this case) should be omitted/ignored.

Programming is about solving real-world problems, not about trying to write the best, most complete code that satisfies all checkers and linters out there on the web.

Also, your solution may cause the program to run slightly slower, which is acceptable if the purpose or cause is important, but unacceptable if it's just to satisfy mypy or other typing problems. Tricking type checkers in believing that your type is correct is not as good as passing-in what ever you want as long as the code works (run smoothly, fulfills the purpose and its job, and don't raise errors, either by itself or a TypeError raised by python).

Writing additional classes just for the purpose of type restrictions also pollutes namespace. It's Ok for small programs, not exactly Ok if the program is large and you do this for every parameter of the functions and methods.

Casting is a good (and sometimes required) concept in other programming languages, such as Java or C, but absolutely not needed in Python. Please remember that Python is a dynamically-typed language, so don't apply the statically-typed language habits to a dynamically-typed language. It don't fit well, just creates trouble and noise.

I'm not sure why you are arguing against "statically-typed language habits" in a question about static typing.

@chepner to be fair, sometimes "stop writing 50 lines of code to make one call pass mypy - document the behavior, put there Any/ignore and go on" is an important alternative to keep in mind. I've seen a small TypeScript project completely lost in "correct" typing - so that signatures, types and interfaces take more space and mental effort than the underlying runtime code. And that, uhm, isn't something I enjoy touching let alone maintaining, it would have been marginally better with a few anys.

(I don't think it's the case here, static config validation is likely helpful enough to justify a bunch of TypedDict's)

@chepner I though that I did say in my comment that Python is a dynamically-typed language. Typing systems are one of the most fundamental parts of a language, and using habits from a different typing system into the current one is absolutely not a good idea.

@chepner Every typing system have their own purpose and benefits, it's not like I'm refuting the static typing model as a whole, but don't confuse different typing systems with other ones. Python is the only one of the popular languages that use dynamic-typing, and if people start using Python like a statically-typed language, then there's no widely-used language out there that uses dynamical-typing. Thus, no one can enjoy the benefits of dynamic typed-language, and in time it'll be forgotten.

@chepner Thus, I think it is Python and the Python community's responsibility to preserve a widely-used language that uses dynamic-typing. However, the recent trends in Python shows ever increasing popularity among the new typing module, and dynamic typing programming concept such as duck-typing and polymorphism are generally forgotten already. I observed that newer books on Python doesn't even mention polymorphism, and even it they did, they see it as just a concept that shouldn't actually be used.

@chepner After seeing this trend, I began researching other dynamically-typed language, but found that they either doesn't have enough popularity to be widely-used and thus also have a relatively small community, or that they do a relatively (compared to Python) bad job of implementing the module. Yet others have severe problems other than the typing module, such as absurd and/or incomprehensible syntax  (Lisp, for example), extremely expressive design that leads to unmanageable code (Perl), or extremely useful but only in a niche (or relatively niche) field (JavaScript and PHP).

@chepner I guess of the above languages mentioned, only JavaScript and PHP have a possibility of continuing the programming concept of dynamic-typing.

@chepner However, as these two are only used in websites, other applications like systems programming, artificial intelligence, data analysis, computer graphics, back-end development, programming language development and design of compilers, ... etc. don't get to enjoy the benefits of dynamically-typed language. Thus, unless a new, popular dynamically-typed language appears on the horizon, we, as Python users and lovers and part of the community, mustn't forget the importance of preserving the dynamic-typing module in Python.

@chepner For those who prefer statical typing systems, I recommend that they learn Java, C, C++ and C#. All of those are popular programming languages that are renowned for many strengths. There's actually no need or reason to choose Python and try to change it to static than just use the originally static languages.

Your problem is just because of a type checking issue. If TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__() can accept an object rather than an int, then it should be just fine. You probably can just ignore the type checking issues. They are for cases where the methods/function called actually doesn't accept an object of type object and results in an TypeError. If it's just a type annotation issue, I suggest you either ignore it or change the annotation to something like this (given that TimedRotatingFileHandler is your own class and thus you can change it):
def __init__(self, logfile: File, backupCount: int|object, *args, **kwargs):
    # code here


You're right, I don't have time to make type checking work on my dictionary. TimedRotatingFileHandler isn't my class, and it refuses to accept an object instead of an int for backupCount. I figured out that this can be fixed using TypedDict but the overhead to make this work is seemingly incredible.

This fixes the wrong problem. TimedRotatingFileHandler is specific that it needs an int. Rather than loosening this restriction, you should be ensuring that mypy knows the precise type of config.

@chepner I wonder if TimedRotatingFileHandler is a library class. If it's not the user's own class, then your answer is better than mine. However, if it's OP's own class, then it's best to either ignore the type checking issue or change the type annotation in the class definition as stated in my post. Also, my opinion is that type annotations only causes unnecessary noise and problems that distract programmers from actual problems to solve, rather than doing any good at all. That's just my opinion, of course.

@wormram Can you please tell me what's wrong with my answer that deserves to be unaccepted? Didn't you say in an earlier comment that using TypedDict create overhead and also that you don't have time for that?
